# How best to secure my Web API called by an Azure function?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory, restful-authentication, azure-authentication

I've been tasked with creating an Azure Function which will be triggered from a Service Bus Topic. The function will then be required to write back data to our database which is hosted internally on our network. The problem I have is that the server the database resides does not have an external IP.

What I will do to overcome this issue is to create a Web API which will reside on our internal network, hosted on IIS on a server which does have an external IP. The function will call the API and the API will write the data back to the database, with no problems faced.

The big issue I now have is how to secure the API appropriately. I would like some direction as to how best to do this, as there will be no client apps, front facing portals, or a list of credentials that need stored. I've read up on Azure AD authentication, which is all good and well for the Azure function, but as the Web API is outside Azure and on the internal network, I'm not sure this is the solution. I'm aware of JWT and have used this on another API I've developed for a 3rd party client, where secret keys and an account was created, but is there a requirement to create an account for an internal use, I'm not so sure.

Could anyone please let me know the right solution for the problem faced above? I've read so much documentation on securing APIs I'm becoming more and more confused.

Thanks in advance to anyone who has any suggestions :)

Answer (score 0):

If the circumstances allow it, an approach I've used many times is to just validate against a setting value. This is similar to what Azure Functions offer out of the box. Depending, you could either store it directly as a setting (cleartext) in the function settings, or use a KeyVault to store it securely.

This is very simply to implement and usually works fine for these kinds of point to point integrations that are more or less permanent.

Alternatively, write a program which does what the function does, but run it on-prem and avoid the entire integration need. Adding jwt/service principals seems excessive.